# html email with tables send from plsql package and viewed in lotus notes

Tags: html, email, plsql, smtp, lotus-notes

I was trying to send html from oracle plsql package..the code worked and i received the email in lotus notes client.
But the html table gets shrunk when window size is changed in lotus notes.

Please help me what should i put in html code to avoid this..
In the table style, i had included table layout : fixed, cellpadding and cellspacing to zero also included max width and min width and max height and min height to lock the table from getting shrunk. Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table.table1 {
        Cellspacing: 0;
        Cellpadding: 0;
        max-width:500pt;
        min-width:500pt;
        border: 1px solid black;
        Border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }
      Tr,td {
        Border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table1">
      <tr> <td>Sl.no</td> <td>Date</td> <td>Item Name</td> <td>Number of items</td> <td>Delivery date</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>1</td> <td>17 Nov 2016</td> <td>Battery</td> <td>11</td> <td>20 Dec 2016</td> </tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

But all of this fails in lotus notes 8.5.

Comment: You haven't shown your HTML or mentioned what version(s) of Lotus Notes you are targeting. It's very unlikely that anyone can help you without at least that much information.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<style>
table.table1{
Cellspacing: 0;
Cellpadding: 0;
max-width:500pt;
min-width:500pt;

border: 1px solid black;
Border-collapse: collapse;
table-layout: fixed;
}
Tr,td{
Border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table1">
<tr>
<td>Sl.no</td> 
<td>Date</td> 
<td>Item Name</td> 
<td>Number of items</td> 
<td>Delivery date</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td> 
<td>17 Nov 2016</td> 
<td>Battery</td> 
<td>11</td> 
<td>20 Dec 2016</td> 
</tr>

</body></html>

Comment: Another item i noticed is when trying to forwarf the mail received using html,lotus notes shrinking it always to 7 inches.

Comment: Lotus Notes was first released more than 25 years ago. There are dozens of different versions in use. What version(s) have you tested this with.

Comment: Lotus notes 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I have not figured out a reliable way to get the Lotus Notes client to do style tags.<sup>[1]</sup> You could try the style attributes within each cell, but your best bet is to avoid CSS wherever possible and, however painful it may be, force your table width with a row like<sup>2</sup>

```
<tr><td colspan="5"><img width="500" height="1" src="../../DelOptionSpacer.gif"/></td></tr>
```

Where the source leads to the database's DelOptionSpacer.gif image resource (which is a clear gif in the 9.0 mail template... not sure about 8.5). You might be better off with a src of `="../../DelOptionSpacer.gif?OpenImageResource"`

Other tips:

- You are missing your `</table>` tag at the end.
- You might wish to consider using `<th>` tags instead of `<td>` tags in the first row.

I know Domino can be frustrating sometimes! I often tell people it's like building with Duplo blocks - you can get close to what you want VERY quickly but, often, it's not easy to get exactly what you want.

---

*<sup>1</sup> - Hopefully I'm wrong??? Anyone???*

*<sup>2</sup> - untested*

Comment: @Richard...is there any way to overcome the situation mentioned in my last comment